# Testing Code in iTextSharp

Tags: unit-testing, testing, itext

Is it possible to perform TDD when creating code with iTextSharp? If not, is there any kind of testing to check your outputs?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a full .Net solution for you but there is an open source Java version called [JpdfUnit](http://jpdfunit.sourceforge.net/index.html) that may or may not be helpful. It uses Apache's [PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) behind the scenes to do the actual PDF reading. The good news is that there is a [.Net wrapper for PDFBox](http://www.pdfbox.org/userguide/dot_net.html). You'll have to roll your own unit tests but hopefully it will be helpful. Here's a link to someone that gives a little more information on [how to use PDFBox.net](http://naspinski.net/post/ParsingReading-a-PDF-file-with-C-and-AspNet-to-text.aspx).

PDF is mostly a visual medium, however, so if you want to test if things "look right", you'll have to manually so that unfortunately.